# SharePoint 2010 asmx Web Service throws 401 after 10 hours

Tags: web-services, 401

We've recently upgraded our existing SharePoint 2007 site to SharePoint 2010.  We have a couple of internal and external sites that make use of the asmx web services provided by SharePoint.

We currently have an issue where after 8 - 10 hours all requests from the privileged account will start receiving 401.0 access denied errors from IIS7.  A app pool recycle will solve the problem, and then 8 - 10 hours the same thing happens again.  While one priviledged account is receiving 401's, other accounts will work for 8 - 10 hours.

See our IIS7 Logs below:

2011-09-26 00:00:45 10.45.25.x POST /_vti_bin/lists.asmx - 12345 - 10.45.25.x Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+4.0.30319.237) 401 0 0 3

2011-09-26 00:00:45 10.45.25.x POST /_vti_bin/lists.asmx - 12345 0#.w|domain\account 10.45.25.x Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+4.0.30319.237) 401 0 0 289

2011-09-26 00:02:45 10.45.25.x POST /_vti_bin/lists.asmx - 12345 - 10.45.25.x Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+4.0.30319.237) 401 0 0 5

2011-09-26 00:02:45 10.45.25.x POST /_vti_bin/lists.asmx - 12345 0#.w|\ 10.45.25.x Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+4.0.30319.237) 401 0 0 298

2011-09-26 00:05:06 10.45.25.x POST /_vti_bin/lists.asmx - 12345 - 10.45.25.x Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+4.0.30319.237) 401 0 0 6

2011-09-26 00:05:06 10.45.25.x POST /_vti_bin/lists.asmx - 12345 0#.w|domain\account 10.45.25.x Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+4.0.30319.237) 401 0 0 296

We are calling these services on its own AAM (Port 12345) that is configured as a Intranet zone.  Windows and Anonymous authentication are both enabled.

Comment: Ignoring the IIS log for a minute, are you seeing anything in the ULS logs or system application logs?

Comment: During that same time, what jobs are running in SharePoint?

Comment: I see nothing happening repeatedly in the Application Log, or anything that looks like it would deny the account in the ULS log.  Everytime it happens there are different messages in both.  In fact the only thing I see in the ULS log is the CAML query I'm using against the web services

Comment: Just a thought, Todd Klindt was talking about seeing strange access denied messages with processes over night. The cause was a Group Policy, he recreated the issue by applying group policy using gpupdate /force. Something to try out. Have you logged any performance counters and checked for increase in memory usage maybe the web service is chewing up resources?

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that resources are running out / not getting returned  in time.

I would suggest that you apply a performance trace on .net counters (CLR for SQL for example), TCP connections and any other resource that you feel you application will consume over the soak test.

Look for items that fit a profile of resources that are pulled from a pool but which will not necessarily be returned as quickly as you would expect (esp. over time).

I had a similar issue with a BizTalk application once and it was the available SQL connection pool that eventually got fully consumed even though the original pool size was very large.